# Swift - Working with data returned from Firestore fetching

Tags: swift, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore, core-data, casting

I have a **CoreData object** called `FavoriteArticle`. I store it in **Firestore** as a collection of objects for each user I have.

This is my CoreData:
[my CoreData entity of FavoriteArticle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khWUA.png)

This is my Firestore:
[my Firestore hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYlmK.png)

When I try to fetch the savedArticles of the currentUser I encounter an issue that I can't figure out how to solve:

The data that returns is of type `[String:Any]` while I need it to be `[String:FavoriteArticle]` to pass it to the `completionHandler` and use it later on in my app. I cannot user Firebase's custom objects code because CoreData does not conform to the `Codable`.

This is my current poor attempt of a workaround but my app keeps crushing on the line of `favoriteArticle.title = "\(document.data()["title"])"` with the error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FavoriteArticle setTitle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000022ca840'` -

```
func fetchUserDataCollection(uid: String, completionHandler: @escaping(String?,[String : FavoriteArticle]?) -> ()) {
    
    let docRef = database.collection("Users").document(uid).collection("savedArticles")
    docRef.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            completionHandler("Error getting documents: \(error)",nil)
        } else {
            var resultsDictionary: [String: FavoriteArticle] = [:]
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                let favoriteArticle = FavoriteArticle()
                print(document.data()["title"] as! String)
                favoriteArticle.title = "\(document.data()["title"])"
                favoriteArticle.isFavorite = (document.data()["isFavorite"] as? Bool)!
                favoriteArticle.author = document.data()["author"] as! String
                favoriteArticle.topic = document.data()["topic"] as! String
                favoriteArticle.imageUrl = document.data()["imageUrl"] as! String
                favoriteArticle.content = document.data()["content"] as! String
                favoriteArticle.url = document.data()["url"] as! String
                favoriteArticle.date = document.data()["date"] as! String
                
                resultsDictionary[document.documentID] = favoriteArticle
            }
            completionHandler(nil,resultsDictionary)
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: _"...CoreData does not conform to the Codable"_, you can make `FavoriteArticle` conform to `Codable`. Do some searching and you will find examples on how to do it.

Comment: Please include the error message.

Comment: Updated my question with the error. Putting it here too - `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FavoriteArticle setTitle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000022ca840'` @burnsi

Comment: `let favoriteArticle = FavoriteArticle()`, this must be a custom init, what are you doing in that init method?

Comment: Yes turns out that the issue was in the line of initialization. Thanks. @JoakimDanielson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with the line `let favoriteArticle = FavoriteArticle()` because I forgot to add the context inside it. Changing to:

```
let favoriteArticle = FavoriteArticle(context: (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext)
```

fixed the issue